# Only 50 items are displayed when displaying search results with the azure search service

Tags: azure-cognitive-search, azure-search-.net-sdk

When I get the result of a search I see this

[image]

That is, I get 298 results but only 50 values

I use this in my web API

```
private async Task<SearchResults<Oferta>> RunQueryAsync(SearchData model)
{
  InitSearch();
  var options = new SearchOptions()
  {
    IncludeTotalCount = true
  };

  options.HighlightFields.Add("content");
  options.HighlightPreTag = "<mark>";
  options.HighlightPostTag = "</mark>";
  options.Select.Add("metadata_storage_path");
  options.Select.Add("content");

  model.resultList = await _searchClient.SearchAsync<Oferta>(model.searchText, options).ConfigureAwait(false);

  model.resultList.GetResults().ToList().ForEach(r => {

  .....
  })

return model.resultList;
```

In the loop I access the 298 returned elements and in all of them I decode the value of Document.metadata_storage_path since it is an index that analyzes files stored in blobs of a storage account, but when returning model.resulList only appears in the first 50 the decoded value in the remainder is still base 64 encoded

[image]

Any idea, please?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Please add [`Size`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.search.documents.searchoptions.size?view=azure-dotnet#azure-search-documents-searchoptions-size) to your `SearchOptions` and set its value to a number less than or equal to 1000. Your code would be something like:

```
var options = new SearchOptions()
{
    IncludeTotalCount = true,
    Size = 1000
};
```

`Size` parameter maps to `$top` query parameter in [`Search Documents REST API`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/search-documents). If no value is specified for the `$top` parameter, then 50 documents are returned by default.

[image]

Comment: In a single request, a maximum of 1000 documents will be returned. If there are more than 1000 documents, then you would get the next page link in the result. You can use that to get next set of documents.

Answer (score 0):

With this code I get all the results even if they are more than 1000 And the calling front end receives all the values with the correctly decoded path

```
private async Task<List<SearchResult<Oferta>>> RunQueryAsync(SearchData model)
{
  InitSearch();
  var options = new SearchOptions()
  {
    IncludeTotalCount = true
  };

  options.HighlightFields.Add("content");
  options.HighlightPreTag = "<mark>";
  options.HighlightPostTag = "</mark>";
  options.Select.Add("metadata_storage_path");
  options.Select.Add("content");

  int currentPage = 0;
  int pageSize = 50;
  bool hasMoreResults = true;
  List<SearchResult<Oferta>> allResults = new List<SearchResult<Oferta>>();

  while (hasMoreResults)
  {
    options.Skip = currentPage * pageSize;
    options.Size = pageSize;

    model.resultList = await _searchClient.SearchAsync<Oferta>(model.searchText, options).ConfigureAwait(false);

    var currentResults = model.resultList.GetResults().ToList();
    currentResults.ForEach(r => {
      string pathCodificado = r.Document.metadata_storage_path;

      r.Document.metadata_storage_path = DecodeBase64(r.Document.metadata_storage_path);
      if (r.Document.metadata_storage_path != "")
      {
        r.Document.metadata_storage_path = r.Document.metadata_storage_path.Substring(62);
        r.Document.year = ExtraerAño(r.Document.metadata_storage_path);
      }
      else//Se ha producido algun error decodificando
      {
        r.Document.metadata_storage_path = pathCodificado;
        r.Document.year = -1;
      }
    });

    allResults.AddRange(currentResults);

    hasMoreResults = model.resultList.TotalCount > (currentPage + 1) * pageSize;

    currentPage++;
  }

    
  return allResults;
}
```

Pagination is performed in the RunQueryAsync method and returns a complete list of decoded results